# Angular 14 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup) very slow

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

After I update my Angular Application from Angular 7.2.11 to Angular 14.0.0

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.6
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: 8.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.6

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.6
`@angular-devkit/core            14.0.6`
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.6
----------
```

`ng serve` generating browser application bundles takes horrible long.

```
 / Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup) ...
```

Comment: Remove your `node_module` & `package-lock.json` run `npm install` again.
Also, for testing purposes disable your antivirus solution, this will help you understand where the problem is. Honestly, in Angular 14 the building process it's quite fast.

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733861/angular-12-generating-browser-application-bundles-phase-sealing-very-slow?rq=1) helps.

Comment: For me, using @for in the SCSS file with too many repetitions caused the problem. Reducing the number of loops solved it.

Comment: In my scenario, my angular server was completely hung on this step. No amount of waiting would allow angular to continue. The cause was actually a TS compiler issue. I had a recursive type that was defined and had accidentally used an `any` type value as an argument to the generic recursive type I wanted to use. I believe the TS compiler was stuck in an infinite loop of this recursive type.