Angular UI stuck at 'phase: building'
i've generated single layer .net with angular app and now i cant get ui to start.
Its stuck on

Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...

when i run yard start.
I have tried deleting node_moduele, setting "defaultConfiguration": "development" (was production), restarting vs code, regenerating abp project, updating yarn and dependencies, and all of that didn't help. I am lost don't know what else to do.

what about nodejs and npm version? Check the minimum version of nodejs required for your angular version

It looks like this happens with Angular 11, [Angular 12])https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733861/angular-12-generating-browser-application-bundles-phase-sealing-very-slow) and Angular 14.
